# Sass back nesting issue

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to back nest specifically to the parent of the css nest I'm in. Meaning, my current set up is a parent class to a span to a before pseudo. I need to change a style on the pseudo based on a modifier on the parent. If I do this:

```
.parent {
    span {
       &:before {
          // styles

          .modifier & {
             // Other styles
          }
       }
   }
}
```

The output is `.modifier .parent span:before` What I need is `.parent.modifier span:before`

Isn't there a way to do this without adding the modifier to the parent and pathing to the pseudo again? This is what I want to avoid.

```
.parent {
    span {
       &:before {
          // styles
       }
   }
   &.modifier {
       span {
          &:before {
             // Other Styles
          }
       }    
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an issue about concatenation as opposed to back nesting. Maybe I'm just confused, but I don't see how that helps my question.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused what you were asking xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly possible, it does require the use of some of the less known sass functions `@at-root`, `& ampersand` and string interpolation `#{}`.

Basically it works in the following manner;

1. Use `@at-root` to jump outside of the class, to the 'root'.
2. We place our class after that, I've used `.--modifer-is-red`.
3. We attach the classes that we jumped outside of by using interpolation of the `&`, `#{&}`.

[Live Example](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6396254a9f4ccce90d95d33c353529e3)

#### Example used for clarity

```
.parent {
  span {
     &:before {
      // styles
      color: black;

      // Modifiers attached to the parent
      @at-root .--modifier-is-red#{&} {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
}

// output
// .--modifier-is-red.parent span:before {
//   color: red;
// }
```

#### Exact example to reflect your code

```
.parent {
    span {
       &:before {
          // styles
          @at-root .modifier#{&} {
             // Other styles
          }
       }
   }
}
```

There is some limitations to this, also it does look slightly odd that the modifier is placed before the parent in the output, but the browser doesn't mind.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought I tried everything with the @at-root function but I guess didn't think to place it and the modifier before the #{$}

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there a way to do this without adding the modifier to the parent and pathing to the pseudo again?

No, because you only have the `&` variable to work with, which is always a single unit consisting of the entire complex selector. You can't specify where exactly *in the middle of the complex selector* you want your modifier to go. The best you can do is attach it as a compound selector or use it with a combinator.

Comment: The answer given by @shaune seems to be correct. It also works for me.